# Deploying a MVC4 website to Azure storage

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, azure

I am developing a website in Mvc4 using visual studio 2012 and now I am facing a problem regarding web deployment or I can say that I'm not getting solution for this problem.

My problem is that I want to publish my website from my website view I want to give a button in home page of my website as I click on that button my database updates in IIS or azure server. How can I do this any idea about it ??

I am Currently Using Azure Storage and IIS server for local testing.

Comment: May I ask you why did you _unaccept_ my answer after 15 months later?

Answer (score 1):

- if you want to do deploy for "Azure WebSite" and not "Azure WebRole" you may use FTP transfer.
- if you want to do deploy for WebRole, the first thing you have to open Remote Desktop on it and probably PowerShell will help you to deploy.  You may find more details on that subject in [Azure Enable Web Deploy via automated deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12574999/azure-enable-web-deploy-via-automated-deployment) and [Powershell - Create Azure Deployment Package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15717385/powershell-create-azure-deployment-package)

Also please keep in mind that your infrastructure must be in separate environment.  If you try to control publish/deploy from a same site (say you are on Site X and you are deploying for Site X) if anything goes wrong, you will lose all the control.